# Search with Customer Name in Customer ID field

Tags: acumatica

In Sales Order screen the Customer filed allows to select the customer ID by typing customer name also, how we can add same functionality for Customer ID field in Customer screen. Please have a look at below screenshot for more reference. Any help really appreciated.
Sales Order screen screenshot @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWKyq.png

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned this functionality is present on most screens when typing in the Customer ID field.  However when working with a maintenance screen such as Customer maintenance the key field here IS customer ID.  Or more accurately BAccountID.  So the look up feature behaves a little differently.  This is the same for vendors.

You have a couple options (probably more..)

1. Suggest to your users to type in the first few characters of the customer ID and click on the F3 key.  This will show the select dialog box and jump directly to the first customer match.  Even if the match is the Customer ID itself.
2. You could extend the Customer DAC, add a new unbound field with a PXSELECTOR attribute and write an event to fetch the selected customer and refresh the screen.

Option 2 is not encouraged because it could be confusing to your users and would introduce a quirky way of interacting with the screen.  Also it might be a little tricky to code.